# \indent and \noindent: details from Knuth's The TeXbook

Tags: indentation, tex-core, knuth, parindent

On page 286 in Knuth's book he writes:

> `\noindent` has no effect in horizontal mode.

On the contrary on the page 283 he writes :

> This is exactly like `\indent` except that TeX starts out in horizontal mode
>    with an empty list instead of with an indentation.

**Which statement is correct**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both statements are correct but perhaps nether tell the full truth.

In hmode, `\indent` adds a box of width `\parindent` so looks like a horizontal space, `\noindent` adds an empty hlist, which, as your first quote says, has no effect.

In vmode then both commands cause a new paragraph to start and a new hlist, beginning with an indentation box in the case of `\indent`.

Comment: Small nitpick: it appears that in hmode `\noindent` really does nothing, not even add an empty hlist. (Not that it matters, as far as there being no effect.)

Comment: I'm not sure there is any difference between doing nothing and adding nothing,  arguably a code optimisation, but then the tex code hardly ever does exactly how the observable behaviour is described:-)

Answer (score 10):

When TeX is in vertical mode, `\noindent` starts horizontal mode. When TeX is already in horizontal mode, `\noindent` has no effect. There's no contradiction.

---

The relevant sections from the TeX program:

During program startup (INITEX), §1088 defines the primitive `\noindent` as command code `start_par` with extra param of 0:
[image: noindent defined]

Later in the main control loop (the part where TeX reacts to every token that reaches its “stomach”) if this `start_par` command is seen,

1. If the current mode is vertical mode, then TeX calls `new_graf` with `false`:
   [image: vmode + start_par]
   This `new_graf` does what you expect, in terms of starting a new paragraph:
   [image: new_graf]
   This is what your quoted sentence says too:

   > This is exactly like `\indent` except that TeX starts out in horizontal mode with an empty list instead of with an indentation.
2. Else (horizontal mode or math mode), TeX calls `indent_in_hmode`:
   [image: hmode/mmode + start_par]
   This `indent_in_hmode` as you can see does absolutely nothing at all when `cur_chr = 0` (i.e. `\noindent` instead of `\indent`):
   [image: indent_in_hmode]
   This is what your quoted sentence says too:

   > `\noindent` has no effect in horizontal mode.

---

**Edit**: The corresponding LuaTeX code (in C), for comparison:

- [`tex/commands.c`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/c71be924/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/commands.c#L459):

  ```
  primitive_tex("noindent", start_par_cmd, 0, 0);
  ```
- [`tex/maincontrol.c`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/c71be924/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/maincontrol.c#L456-L463):

  ```
  static void run_start_par_vmode (void) {
      new_graf((cur_chr > 0));
  }

  static void run_start_par (void) {
     if (cur_chr != 2)
         indent_in_hmode();
  }
  ```

  and (leaving out [`new_graf`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/c71be924/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/maincontrol.c#L1781-L1829) as it's a bit long)

  ```
  void indent_in_hmode(void)
  {
      halfword p;
      if (cur_chr > 0) {
          /*tex \.{\\indent} */
          p = new_null_box();
          width(p) = par_indent_par;
          if (abs(mode) == hmode)
              space_factor_par = 1000;
          else
              p = new_sub_box(p);
          tail_append(p);
      }
  }
  ```

  and (in `init_main_control`):

  ```
      jump_table[vmode + start_par_cmd] = run_start_par_vmode;
      jump_table[hmode + start_par_cmd] = run_start_par;
      jump_table[mmode + start_par_cmd] = run_start_par;
  ```

Answer (score 7):

At the top of page 283, Knuth is describing what happens when TeX is in vertical mode and it finds `\noindent`: this command starts horizontal mode appending nothing to the horizontal list.

At the bottom of page 282 the effect of `\indent` is described: it starts horizontal mode appending an empty box as wide as `\parindent` (the width can also be negative).

These two descriptions are in Chapter 24, “Summary of Vertical Mode”.

On page 286 the effect of `\noindent` when TeX is in horizontal mode is described: the effect is doing nothing at all. This is in Chapter 25, “Summary of Horizontal Mode”.

Similarly, the effect of `\noindent` in math mode is described: nothing at all again (page 291). This is in Chapter 26, “Summary of Math Mode”.